# Elasticsearch in Ruby On Rails App and Openshift

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire, openshift

How can I install/use elasticsearch in my R&R app?

[This tutorial](https://openshift.redhat.com/community/blogs/searching-with-elasticsearch-on-openshift) don't work with my App because I use other port 8080 for my app and elasticsearch use same.

EDIT

I change port with this settings:

Elasticsearch's settings:

```
network.host: ${OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP}
transport.tcp.port: 15001
http.port: 15002
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: []
```

Tire's settings:

```
Tire.configure do
  url "127.12.64.1:15001"
  logger "#{Rails.root}/log/elasticsearch.log", level: 'debug'
end
```

And I have this error:

> Request Timeout (RestClient::RequestTimeout)

If I change port to 15002, I have some error too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same approach ... just bind to 15000+ port. Then you can connect to Elastic from your app $OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP:$YOUR_PORT.

Comment: Dakujem Marek. Where can I set these custom setting for tire? I don't see it in Tire's documentation, only logger.

Comment: I found it: https://github.com/lucascaton/elasticsearch_app_example/blob/master/config/initializers/tire.rb

Comment: I have next problem, I'll add it to my post, because it is bigger text.